# Flexbox grid last row wrong margins between items

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout

I'm still experimenting with flexbox, but there's this case I can't solve.

I have this grid

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.wrapper{
   width:100%; 
   oveflow:hidden; 
   margin: 0; 
   padding:0;
}
.container {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
}
.container .item {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 29.666%;
}
```

But when I use this, items in the last row are rendered with a different "space between" them than the items in the previous row.

Look at this picture. This is what I get:

[image]

Trying to fix this, the only thing I can find is to set items' lateral margin as auto, like this

```
.container .item {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  width: 29.666%;
}
```

But now, I have lateral margins between the items and the container border, like this:

[image]

Why does this happen?

Is there a way to solve this other than having negative lateral margins on the container div?

Comment: Negative margins are not solution. maybe you can add a class first-element and make that position;relative; left:20px;

Comment: Can't reproduce. This would be a violation of the spec.

Comment: I fixed without understanding how. Just deleted a lot of dirty old css in the stylesheet. I think it was just some conflict causing this weird behaviour. I would remove this question, it's quite useless. how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I see no defaults.

I did modify a bit your css code given so things can be seen and margin set only from second line:

```css
.wrapper {
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #3197D3;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
}
.container .item {
  display: block;
  width: 29.666%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #FFFF4D;
}
.item:nth-child(3) ~.item {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
/* demo purpose*/

.container:before {
  content:'.'attr(class);
  width:100%;/* will span whole line */
  padding:0.15em;
  font-size:3em;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
.container .item {
  display: flex;
}
.item:before {
  content: attr(class);
  margin: auto;
  color:#3197D3;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the same result you did, but your margins looks a bit weird. I stripped it down to this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: blue; 
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  width: 29.666%;
}

.item:not(:nth-last-child(-n+3)) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```